# Set of diffeomorphisms on a manifold

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-topology, dynamical-systems

It is well known that given a compact smooth boundaryless manifold $M$, the set of diffeomorphisms $Diff^{r}(M)$ of $M$ for $r \geq 1$, is open in $C^{r}(M)$, the set of continuous functions (for example,  Thm. 1.7, in Differential Topology, M. Hirsch).

My question is: does it follow that $Diff^{r + \alpha}(M) \subset C^{r + \alpha}(M)$ is open w.r.t. $C^{r + \alpha}$ topology for $0 < \alpha \leq 1$?
Can someone give me some reference?

Comment: What is $C^{r+\alpha}$ topology?

Comment: It is the Hölder topology. See for example Chap. 3 in "Lectures on Elliptic and Parabolic Equations in Hölder spaces", N. Krylov. Or, to get started, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder_condition